# Selenium WebDriver not finding element using CSS Selector and data attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an input HTML element for first name in signup.

```html
<div class="form-group" data-test="signup-form-first-name">
    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" autocomplete="given-name" class="fbkr-input gray error" value="" background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: pointer;">
    <div aria-live="polite" class="label label-danger">
        First Name is required.
        </div>
</div>
```

The element with label-danger class is only visible if there is an error and the field is empty.
I am trying to test whether that element is visible when testing the signup flow, but every time I try that, it fails. I tried to change the script so it only uses the class (.label-danger), but alas, still nothing.
Here is the code that I am trying that with.

```
    def is_element_error_label_visible(self, element_data_attribute: str) -> bool:
        try:
            element_present = 
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, f". 
            {self._build_data_attribute(element_data_attribute)} .label-danger"))
            WebDriverWait(self.remote_web_driver, 
            15).until(element_present)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True
```

The value that

```
f"{self._build_data_attribute(element_data_attribute)} .label-danger"))
```

returns is: **[data-test="signup-form-first-name"] .label-danger**

Is this an invalid way to get the element using the CSS Selector? Or is there a much simpler way for this. Please keep in my mind that I do not want to use xPath, since I like to keep my code clean, that is why I am using the **data-test** attribute.

Comment: I believe the validation of other field as well like first name, last name etc..To make it robust you can use class name only for the error element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following css selector.

```
expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".label-danger"))
```

---

Update:
While Automating seems you need to click on Sign_up button to see the error without entering data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://fishingbooker.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.btn[href*='signup']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.fbkr-button.yellow"))).click()
try:
    print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#first-name + .label-danger"))).text)
except:
    print("No such element found")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @VedranKorponajić: could you please share the url since it is registration page?

Comment: Sure, it's fishingbooker.com, you just open the Sign up modal. Keep in mind that the data-test attributes are on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python to provide a code snippet. But I would use a partial CSS selector matcher for this situation. Please use it if applicable only.

```
div[class*="label-danger"]
```